# How to create a ring shape in Box2d

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Circles are solid and there's no way to create an empty space inside them, is there?

It is possible to create it using a combination of the basic shapes (Chains/Edges) but I was wondering if there was an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a ring would be draw a larger circle of the primary color, then draw a smaller circle inside of the background color (if it's a solid color.) Otherwise, use a texture with a transparent center.

Comment: I need to add another physical objects inside the ring, it's not just about drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to create a space inside a circle in box2d. ChainShape and EdgeShape will work, but only if you are creating a ring that doesn't move. If you want a dynamic body your only option is compound polygon shape (Body with few convex polygon fixtures). Compound polygon shape is a good idea for static ring too.

Comment: Are you sure that Chain shape is filled? The definition says it's a set of consecutive edges.

Comment: Nop, I wasn't sure. Always thought that ChainShape must form a loop of vertices in order to work. After a quick read through box2d manual turns out I was wrong. I edited my answer